# Disable `pip install` Timeout For Slow Connections

Tags: python, pip, request-timed-out

I recently moved to a place with terrible internet connection. Ever since then I have been having huge issues getting my programming environments set up with all the tools I need - you don't realize how many things you need to download until each one of those things takes over a day.
For this post I would like to try to figure out how to deal with this in pip.

**The Problem**
Almost every time I `pip install` something it ends out timing out somewhere in the middle. It takes many tries until I get lucky enough to have it complete without a time out. This happens with many different things I have tried, big or small. Every time an install fails the next time starts all over again from 0%, no matter how far I got before.
I get something along the lines of

```
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

**What I want to happen**
Ideally I would like to either extend the definition of time pip uses before it declares a timeout or be able to disable the option of a timeout all together.
I am not sure either of these are possible, so if anyone has any other solution for me that would be greatly appreciated as well.

**Other Information**
Not sure this helps any but what I found is that the only reliable way for me to download anything here is using torrents, as they do not restart a download once they lose connection, rather they always continue where they left off. If there is a way to use this fact in any way that would be nice too.

Comment: Can't `--timeout <sec>             Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).` work?

Comment: You can also set the default timeout in a pip config file https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thanks! Seems to be working. I swear I googled this before I posted, don't know how I missed this. If you want to post this as an answer I will be happy to approve it and upvote

Comment: technically correct answer, but could do without the preachy scold.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use option `--timeout <sec>` to set socket time out.

Also, as @Iain Shelvington mentioned, `timeout = <sec>` in [pip configuration](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration) will also work.

*TIP: Every time you want to know something (maybe an option) about a command (tool), before googling, check the manual page of the command by using `man <command>` or use `<command> --help` or `check that command's docs online` will be very useful too.*

Answer (score 1):

To set the `timeout` time to 30sec for example. The easiest way is executing: `pip config global.timeout 30` or going to the pip configuration file ***pip.ini*** located in the directory ***~\AppData\Roaming\pip*** in the case of Windows operating system. If the file does not exist there, create it and write:

```
[global]
timeout = 30
```

.

Comment: `pip config set global.timeout 30`

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider utilising the `--retries <retries>` flag where you can specify the number of retries (in case of connection failure) before the operation is cancelled.

---

Note that it can be used along with the above mentioned "--timeout " flag for more control over the connection persistence and stability.

Example:-

> `pip install numpy --retries 10 --timeout 360`